# Optimum way to use RequireJS with Broccoli

Tags: javascript, requirejs, broccolijs

We have an application using RequireJS AMD modules that we're trying to build using Broccoli. I thought it might be feasible to generate just one JavaScript file with sourcemaps and use that 
both for development and deployment (perhaps only not running uglify to make build faster).

However, it takes quite a long time for r.js optimizer to run, so that doesn't seem to be the way. Is there a way to build my app as one file while still achieving reasonably fast builds on every file change? Or should I just let RequireJS load my modules one by one during development?

The information on this topic seems to be quite fragmented.

Comment: What to do during development depends on the specifics of the project. What works well on a small project may not scale on a larger one. What works well when your development model is to run everything locally may not work well when your development code needs to run on a remote server, etc.

Comment: Running development code on a remote server is definitely something I'd like to do from time to time and loading individual files just doesn't work in this case for performance reasons...